# Text Starting From New Line

Tags: texmaker

I am creating a resume using Texmaker by following this project. [link](https://github.com/dnl-blkv/mcdowell-cv)

```
\documentclass[]{mcdowellcv}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\name{Name Here}
\address{Address here \linebreak XYZ}
\contacts{+1 9999999999 \linebreak xyz@gmail.com}

\begin{document}

    % Print the header
    \makeheader

    \begin{cvsection}{Education}
        \begin{cvsubsection}{City Name State}{Some Lengthy College     Name Some Lenghty}{2013}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Bachelor of Technology in Computer Science and     Engineering
            \end{itemize}
        \end{cvsubsection}
    \end{cvsection}

\end{document}
```

Output is like this.

[image]

What I want to achieve is that the college name should remain in the same line as there is some space to the left and right side.

Comment: Is the documentclass available somewhere?

Comment: yes its available

Comment: may I ask where it is available?

Comment: I am using this https://github.com/dnl-blkv/mcdowell-cv

Comment: This is the class https://github.com/dnl-blkv/mcdowell-cv/blob/master/mcdowellcv.cls

Comment: It would have been better to add that to the question rather than have an external link as if the class changes the question (which is archived forever here)  won't ,make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick and dirty: put the name of your college in a box

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass[]{mcdowellcv}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\name{Name Here}
\address{Address here \linebreak XYZ}
\contacts{+1 9999999999 \linebreak xyz@gmail.com}

\begin{document}

    % Print the header
    \makeheader

    \begin{cvsection}{Education}
        \begin{cvsubsection}{City Name State}{\mbox{Some Lengthy College Name Some Lenghty}}{2013}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Bachelor of Technology in Computer Science and     Engineering
            \end{itemize}
        \end{cvsubsection}
    \end{cvsection}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @efex09 Not a fix, just a quick hack :)